Issue with downloading apple tap for downloading GPTK
I am trying to play Hogwarts legacy on my computer so Im downloading GPTK so I can do so since it only runs on PC. I am in the process of build in this website that i will link below and I'm on the second step. My terminal then said this which i will also link below. How do I fix this?
https://www.applegamingwiki.com/wiki/Game_Porting_Toolkit
I am not sure when I so called disabled it like it says in the code but I don't remember doing so. If someone could let me know how to give it permission again that would be great!
